# C# taking large negative no. as a positive value

Tags: c#, if-statement, double, eulers-number

To cut to the chase, when performing some calculations within my code i have a result that is something like. 7.6742332E-30, i have this value stored in a double variable for example, double result = 7.6742332E-30;

When i later check whether this value is greater than 0 the result is true, that it is greater than 0, i assume due to the 7.6742332.

So my question is this, why is the E-30 not being considered and how do i resolve this?

Any advice would be great and thanks so much i advance!

Comment: 7E-30 (or 7*10^-30) is (just) greater than zero, what did you expect?

Comment: You obviously don't know the [`E notation` aka `Scientific notation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_notation#E_notation). Basically, `Ex` is a shortcut for `* 10^x` (with x being a number). So `E-30` means `* 10^-30`, which is the same as `* 0.000000000000000000000000000001` (30 zeroes in front of the 1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

7.6742332E-30 is 0.0000000000000000000000000000076742332, which is a positive number.

Comment: My bad! Think i need to take a time out! Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 1):

7.6742332E-30 mathematcally equals `7.6742332 x 10^-30` which is a positive number